# How to identify error with scipy.stats.chisquare returns negative values?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, chi-squared

I am using spyder 3.1.3 with python 3.6.8 under window 10, having scipy 1.2.1. I want to get the chisquare value but notice there is negative values returned. Why is that?

```
from scipy.stats import chisquare
chisquare(f_obs=[2,1], f_exp=[100000,1])
#Power_divergenceResult(statistic=14096.65412, pvalue=0.0)
```

but

```
chisquare(f_obs=[2,1], f_exp=[1000000,1])
#Power_divergenceResult(statistic=-731.379964, pvalue=1.0)
```

Is there an upperbound for expect values in chisquare? Thanks.

Comment: I tried your code in scipy 1.1.0 and got the expected answers. Perhaps there is a bug in 1.2.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows, the default integer type for numpy arrays is 32 bit.  I can reproduce the problem by passing numpy arrays with dtype `np.int32` to `chisquare`:

```
In [5]: chisquare(f_obs=np.array([2,1], dtype=np.int32), f_exp=np.array([1000000,1], dtype=np.int32))                    
Out[5]: Power_divergenceResult(statistic=-731.379964, pvalue=1.0)
```

This is a bug.  I created an issue for this on the SciPy github site: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/10159

To work around the problem, convert the input arguments to arrays with data type `numpy.int64` or `numpy.float64`:

```
In [6]: chisquare(f_obs=np.array([2,1], dtype=np.int64), f_exp=np.array([1000000,1], dtype=np.int64))                    
Out[6]: Power_divergenceResult(statistic=999996.000004, pvalue=0.0)

In [7]: chisquare(f_obs=np.array([2,1], dtype=np.float64), f_exp=np.array([1000000,1], dtype=np.float64))                
Out[7]: Power_divergenceResult(statistic=999996.000004, pvalue=0.0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It solves my problem, I was very curious why it worked under mac os but not windows.